# How to join and check if data exist in multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble with finding and replacing the equivalent in the current code of 3 dataframe.
Currently I have df_A join with df_C on ITEM_ID, COMPONENT, SUB_COMPONENT then join with df_B on VENDOR_ID. But I have the problem of finding the equivalent substitute on the items based on the column "NOTE" of df_C, for example if the COMPONENT and SUBCOMPONENT have the same NOTE for "EMHC1" then any of the items in the columns "1st_ITEM_REQUIRED" are interchangeable. For example if item R688 is out of stock, it could be replaced with R325.

Expected output:

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
import io

# Create a dictionary with the provided data
data_A = {
    "ITEM_ID": ["I3067", "I3067", "I3067", "I3067"],
    "ITEM_NM": ["ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A"],
    "COMPONENT": [20, 20, 30, 50],
    "SUBCOMPONENT": [20, 40, 40, 20],
    "VENDOR_ID": [699221, 699221, 699221, 699221],
    "INVOICE_DT": ["2023-01-05", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-05"]
}

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data_A)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df_A)

data_B = {
    "VENDOR_ID": [699221, 699221, 699221, 699221],
    "VENDOR_NAME": ["Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B"],
    "ITEM_STATUS": ["OOS", "IS", "IS", "OOS"],
    "ITEM_CD": ["R688", "C1024", "R786", "R325"],
    "ITEM_NM": ["Heat and Sun Reflect", "Safety Gloves", "Essentials (R786)", "Automated Dispenser (ATD)"],
    "CURR_IND": ["Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    "EXPIRE_DT": ["2020-06-16", "2024-06-30", "2025-03-31", "9999-12-31"],
    "ITEM_STATUS": ["InValid", "Valid", "Valid", "Valid"]
}

df_B = pd.DataFrame(data_B)

print(df_B)

data_C = """
ITEM_ID ITEM_NM COMPONENT   SUBCOMPONENT    NOTE    1st_ITEM_REQUIRED   2nd_ITEM_REQUIRED
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  20  EMHC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  20  EMHC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  20  EMHC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  20  EMHC1   R325    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  40  EMLC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  40  EMLC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  40  EMLC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  40  EMLC1   R325    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  50  EMTC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  50  EMTC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  50  EMTC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   20  50  EMTC1   R325    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   30  40  EMMC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   30  40  EMMC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   30  40  EMMC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   30  40  EMMC1   R325    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  10  EMWC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  10  EMWC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  10  EMWC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  10  EMWC1   R325    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  20  EMUC1   C1024   R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  20  EMUC1   5657    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  20  EMUC1   R688    R786
I3067   ITEM SAMPLE A   50  20  EMUC1   R325    R786
"""

# Read the data as a DataFrame
df_C = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_C), delim_whitespace=True)

print(df_C)

# Perform the first join on ITEM_ID, COMPONENT, and SUBCOMPONENT
df_merged = pd.merge(df_A, df_C, on=['ITEM_ID', 'COMPONENT', 'SUBCOMPONENT'])

# Join the merged DataFrame with df_B on VENDOR_ID
df_final = df_merged.merge(df_B, on="VENDOR_ID")

print(df_final)

##### Expected output

expected_output = {
    "ITEM_ID": ["I3067"] * 9,
    "ITEM_NM": ["ITEM SAMPLE A"] * 9,
    "COMPONENT": [20] * 9,
    "SUBCOMPONENT": [20, 40, 20, 40, 20, 40, 20, 40, 50],
    "NOTE": ["EMHC1"] * 4 + ["EMLC1"] * 4 + ["EMTC1"],
    "1st_ITEM_REQUIRED": ["C1024", "5657", "R688", "R325", "C1024", "5657", "R688", "R325", "R1024"],
    "2nd_ITEM_REQUIRED": ["R786"] * 9,
    "1st_ITEM_FROMVENDOR": ["C1024", "5657", "R688", "R325", "C1024", "5657", "R688", "R325", "C1024"],
    "ITEM_STATUS": ["In Stock", "Not Available", "Out Of Stock", "In Stock", "In Stock", "Not Available", "Out Of Stock", "In Stock", "Out Of Stock"],
    "VENDOR_ID": [699221] * 9,
    "INVOICE_DT": ["2023-01-05"] * 9,
    "Row Status": [
        "Keep (Has equivalent)",
        "Delete (Has equivalent)",
        "Delete (Has equivalent)",
        "Keep (Has equivalent)",
        "Keep (Has equivalent)",
        "Delete (Has equivalent)",
        "Delete (Has equivalent)",
        "Keep (Has equivalent)",
        "Keep (Does not have equivalent)"
    ]
}

df_expected_output = pd.DataFrame(expected_output)

print(df_expected_output)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you please [edit] your question with actual and expected output for your given input data.

Comment: I have added the expected output to further explain my thoughts

Comment: You don't have common keys between df_A and df_B, so that is producing an empty dataframe

Comment: Yes, that is why i have to merge df_A and df_C to a merged df then use that merged_df to merge with df_B on "VENDOR_ID"

Answer (score 0):

I think something may be going awry when you import the data for df_C. I copied the data over and it worked just fine:

```
import pandas as pd

data_A = {
    "ITEM_ID": ["I3067", "I3067", "I3067", "I3067"],
    "ITEM_NM": ["ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A", "ITEM SAMPLE A"],
    "COMPONENT": [20, 20, 30, 50],
    "SUBCOMPONENT": [20, 40, 40, 20],
    "VENDOR_ID": [699221, 699221, 699221, 699221],
    "INVOICE_DT": ["2023-01-05", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-05"]
}

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
df_A = pd.DataFrame(data_A)

data_B = {
    "VENDOR_ID": [699221, 699221, 699221, 699221],
    "VENDOR_NAME": ["Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B", "Vendor Sample B"],
    "ITEM_STATUS": ["OOS", "IS", "IS", "OOS"],
    "ITEM_CD": ["R688", "C1024", "R786", "R325"],
    "ITEM_NM": ["Heat and Sun Reflect", "Safety Gloves", "Essentials (R786)", "Automated Dispenser (ATD)"],
    "CURR_IND": ["Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    "EXPIRE_DT": ["2020-06-16", "2024-06-30", "2025-03-31", "9999-12-31"],
    "ITEM_STATUS": ["InValid", "Valid", "Valid", "Valid"]
}

df_B = pd.DataFrame(data_B)

import pandas as pd

data_C = [
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 20, "EMHC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 20, "EMHC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 20, "EMHC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 20, "EMHC1", "R325", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 40, "EMLC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 40, "EMLC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 40, "EMLC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 40, "EMLC1", "R325", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 50, "EMTC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 50, "EMTC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 50, "EMTC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 20, 50, "EMTC1", "R325", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 30, 40, "EMMC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 30, 40, "EMMC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 30, 40, "EMMC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 30, 40, "EMMC1", "R325", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 10, "EMWC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 10, "EMWC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 10, "EMWC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 10, "EMWC1", "R325", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 20, "EMUC1", "C1024", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 20, "EMUC1", "5657", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 20, "EMUC1", "R688", "R786"],
    ["I3067", "ITEM SAMPLE A", 50, 20, "EMUC1", "R325", "R786"],
]

columns = ["ITEM_ID", "ITEM_NM", "COMPONENT", "SUBCOMPONENT", "NOTE", "1st_ITEM_REQUIRED", "2nd_ITEM_REQUIRED"]

df_C = pd.DataFrame(data_C, columns=columns)
```

First merge:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_A, df_C, on=['ITEM_ID', 'COMPONENT', 'SUBCOMPONENT'])
```

**Note: The ITEM_NM column is duplicated - would you want to add that to the list of columns to merge on?

Second merge:

```
df_final = df_merged.merge(df_B, on="VENDOR_ID")
```

df_final:

| ITEM_ID | ITEM_NM_x | COMPONENT | SUBCOMPONENT | VENDOR_ID | INVOICE_DT | ITEM_NM_y | NOTE | 1st_ITEM_REQUIRED | 2nd_ITEM_REQUIRED | VENDOR_NAME | ITEM_STATUS | ITEM_CD | ITEM_NM | CURR_IND | EXPIRE_DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I3067 | ITEM SAMPLE A | 20 | 20 | 699221 | 2023-01-05 | ITEM SAMPLE A | EMHC1 | C1024 | R786 | Vendor Sample B | InValid | R688 | Heat and Sun Reflect | Y | 2020-06-16 |
| I3067 | ITEM SAMPLE A | 20 | 20 | 699221 | 2023-01-05 | ITEM SAMPLE A | EMHC1 | C1024 | R786 | Vendor Sample B | Valid | C1024 | Safety Gloves | Y | 2024-06-30 |
| I3067 | ITEM SAMPLE A | 20 | 20 | 699221 | 2023-01-05 | ITEM SAMPLE A | EMHC1 | C1024 | R786 | Vendor Sample B | Valid | R786 | Essentials (R786) | Y | 2025-03-31 |
| I3067 | ITEM SAMPLE A | 20 | 20 | 699221 | 2023-01-05 | ITEM SAMPLE A | EMHC1 | C1024 | R786 | Vendor Sample B | Valid | R325 | Automated Dispenser (ATD) | Y | 9999-12-31 |
| I3067 | ITEM SAMPLE A | 20 | 20 | 699221 | 2023-01-05 | ITEM SAMPLE A | EMHC1 | 5657 | R786 | Vendor Sample B | InValid | R688 | Heat and Sun Reflect | Y | 2020-06-16 |

What I wasn't clear on where the "Row Status" column came from nor the logic you wanted to use if it needed to be created based on row values?